# How to connect to an remote PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu using pgAdmin3?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I'm trying to setup a PostgreSQL database on an Ubuntu machine. I would like to be able to access it using pgAdmin3 from a remote machine. How do I setup this?

I have installed the PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

In my `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` have I this line:

```
host    all    all    all    password
```

so it should accept connections from all IPv4-addresses and passwords should be sent in clear text (this is for development reasons).

If I run this command to see what services is running:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

I can see these lines, that is showing that PostgreSQL is accepting connections on the default port:

```
tcp    0    0    127.0.0.1:5432    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
3561/postgres
```

When I try to connect to this PostgreSQL server from a remote computer on the same local network I get this error message:

> **Server doesn't listen**
>
> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports
>
> *could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "10.0.1.7" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*

I used `postgres` as username and no password. But I have also tried with `postgres` as password. On the local server I can login using:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

How can I connect to a PostgreSQL database running on Ubuntu from a remote machine using pgAdmin3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The line in your netstat report shows that the database is only listening on localhost:5432 (127.0.0.1) for incoming tcp connections.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address  State   PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432  0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  3561/postgres
```

So it can only accept local tcp connections regardless of what permissions you've specified in pg_hba.conf. pg_hba.conf only specifies allowed connections, but does not specify what interfaces your service will listen to.

The addresses the server listens on is specified with the [listen_addresses GUC in postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES).  If you want the server to listen for remote connections you should specify the ip(s) you want it to listen on or `*` to listen on all available interfaces on the host.

To have your postgresql server listen on all interfaces on the host, you should have the following line in postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: but I have already specified `all` in the `pg_hba.conf`file... so it should accept connetions from all ip-addresses.

Comment: Perhaps I could have said it more clearly. pg_hba doesn't specify what the database listens on, only what protocol/db/user/remote-addr connections are permitted.

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix this? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you fix it by putting a line `listen_addresses = '*'` in postgresql.conf and restarting your server.

Comment: Thanks, this solved this problem. Now I just got problems with the default password :(

Comment: I have set a new password with `sudo passwd postgres` but I´m still unable to use it from pgAdmin3.

Comment: I had to use `sudo -u postgres psql postgres` and then `\password postgres` as from this answer http://serverfault.com/a/248162/33300 to get it working, now it works!

Comment: I have confirmed that my setup follow the instructions above. I still cannot connect from a Windows 10 machine running PgAdmin3 to a Ubuntu Server 14.04. Thoughts?

Comment: @LandArch can you telnet to the port from the Win box to the database server?  Perhaps there's some network layer restrictions going on.

Comment: @dbenhur I cannothis failed

Comment: @LandArch look at your network.  Some switch/router/firewall is preventing your win client from connecting to the ubuntu server.